# trying to call api through xhr in Vuejs ,using promise to store response ,doesnt recognize .then()

Tags: api, vuejs2, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

I am trying to call api through xhr ,since axios is not working,how do i store response in a variable ,if i use promise .then() it throws error ,Below is what i am trying to do

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true).then(response=>{

console.log(response);
})
xhr.send();
```

error ,cannot read then

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.it works!!

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var status;
        var data;
        // https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
            status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                successHandler && successHandler(data);
            } else {
                errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
            }
        }
    };
```